# In concrete terms, how do I start using Lighting Network right now?

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network

I have Bitcoin Core installed on Windows and it's fully synced. I am able to send and receive Bitcoin payments.

I hate the fees and waiting, so I want to use Lightning Network.

I've spent countless hours of my life trying to figure this out, but as soon as I get to the part where I'm supposed to use it, I only find nonsense like this: https://docs.lightning.engineering/community-resources/resource-list

What does that page really say? I don't see any "Lightning Core" or anything which I can readily install and use.

What am I missing? What is the *concrete* step for me to take right now in order to enable me to send and receive Lightning Network payments on my computer which already has Bitcoin Core synced and ready?

Please answer clearly. I really want to use and support this thing, but I don't see anything but endless lists of seemingly unrelated software.

Comment: Bitcoin-core has a GUI interface and bitcoind server. Lightining runs as a second layer and communicates with the bitcoind server. Have you reviewed installation instructions from any of the lightning clients? One example, https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning#installation Also see releases page https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/releases

Comment: There is no project called 'Lightning Core', but LND or c-lightning are probably what you're looking for. See: https://github.com/LightningNetwork/lnd, https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md